# Best tool to quickly colour vector shapes

Tags: sketching

I need a tool that lets me quickly colour vector shapes. The Live Paint tool in Illustrator is good BUT the problem is that I also need the same shapes to have a specific stroke, an hand-drawn like stroke, which, as far as I know, you can not get with Illustrator.

Just so you understand the stroke that I need, I am attaching a picture.[image]

**Edits after the first comments:**

Thanks guys and let me explain further:
I got that illustration by using a program/app called Concepts. They have a beautiful hand-drawn brush so my linework is okay. The problem is that when I import it in Illustrator, the Live Paint tool does not work very well cause it does not detect the paths (exactly what Scott said). I closed the gaps with the gap detection tool but it did not work :(
I said "quickly" in the title cause I do architecture drawings and imagine colouring all those windows one by one... nightmare!

@joojaa: how can you get hand-drawn brushes for Illustrator? I mean, exactly like that one in the picture? I tried to create custom brushes but I could never get that kind of look.

Comment: It looks like you already have some hand drawn strokes which could then be filled in using the Live Paint functionality, and the strokes would not be affected. So, I'm not sure if I understand your question properly. Can you please explain further or show what kind of illustration style you are trying to achieve. Thanks.

Comment: "an hand-drawn like stroke, which, as far as I know, you can not get with Illustrator". I dont see why this would be true at all.

Comment: O would guess that your strokes are made with a brush, meaning Live Paint fails because they aren't actually enclosed shapes much of the time? Is that it? If Live Paint isn't going to work, there's no other "quick" method I am aware of.

Comment: @Scott shape builder with fill only option and gap detection. Expansion of strokes and paint on separate layer...

Comment: Post edited with more info :) cheers guys!!

Comment: @Nora there are hundreds of tutorials out there on how to make hand drawn brush strokes in Illustrator whether you have a tablet or not. Could you tell us where you get stuck?

Comment: 1) you can make hand drawn brush strokes in illustrator 2) you can fill with **shape builder** with gap detection enabled. There are also other options Also i have no problem i recreating your work and color in stuff [see here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ypHnu.gif). Anyway we can not answer your question because its asking the wrong thing, your not describing your actual problem, but symptom of problem so you cant get an answer. Everything you claim can not be done, can in fact be done. So you must make your question more fundamental.

Comment: Hey Joojaa, 1) I know I can create hand drawn brush strokes in illustrator but I want that exact stroke look and I do not know how to get that in Illustrator 2) How did you get to draw those strokes in Illustrator? 3) I tried colouring with both the Live Paint (the problem there was that even with the gap detection enabled Illustrator was not picking up the right shapes) and the shape builder (it just took 3 years for Illustrator to colour one window). It might not be a problem for you getting what I want but I can't seem to find a way to get it done

Comment: @Nora 1) no answer for that 2) i didn't you did. I just traced your image 3) Dont select everything in one go do it in sections. (or buy a better computer)

Comment: Oh, you traced it, gotcha. Okay, I'll try with my work computer and see if it is faster. Cheers, Joojaa!